# Get products collection in cronjob

Tags: magento2, collection, cron, products

I have a cron file like **Col.php**. I want to get products collection in my cron file.

code in my file:

```
public function execute()
{
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $collection = $objectManager->create(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory::class
    )->create();

    //Enable status check
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter(
        'status', array('eq' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
    );

    //Stock filter
    $collection->joinField(
        'qty', 'cataloginventory_stock_item', 'qty', 'product_id=entity_id', '{{table}}.stock_id=1', 'left'
    );

    //Visibility check
    $visibility = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility');
    $collection->setVisibility($visibility->getVisibleInSiteIds());

    $this->logger->debug($collection->getSize());
}
```

After executing my cronjob through shell

```
php bin/magento cron:run --group=mygroup_cron_group
```

I am getting error in exception log file:

```
Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'my_db.catalog_category_product_index_store0' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT e.entity_id) FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_status` ON (`at_status`.`row_id` = `e`.`row_id`) AND (`at_status`.`attribute_id` = '97') AND (`at_status`.`store_id` = 0)
 INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index_store0` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=0 AND cat_index.visibility IN(3, 2, 4) AND cat_index.category_id='0' WHERE ((at_status.value = 1)) AND (e.created_in <= 1) AND (e.updated_in > 1) {"exception":"[object] (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception(code: 42): SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'my_db.catalog_category_product_index_store0' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT e.entity_id) FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_status` ON (`at_status`.`row_id` = `e`.`row_id`) AND (`at_status`.`attribute_id` = '97') AND (`at_status`.`store_id` = 0)
 INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index_store0` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=0 AND cat_index.visibility IN(3, 2, 4) AND cat_index.category_id='0' WHERE ((at_status.value = 1)) AND (e.created_in <= 1) AND (e.updated_in > 1)
```

Why it is trying to fetch products from **store 0** how can I get products collection?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try following code.

```
protected $storeManager;
protected $emulation;
protected $productCollectionFactory;
protected $productStatus;
protected $productVisibility;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Store\Model\App\Emulation $emulation,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status $productStatus,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $productVisibility
)
{
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->emulation = $emulation;
    $this->productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
    $this->productStatus = $productStatus;
    $this->productVisibility = $productVisibility;
}

public function execute()
{
    $this->emulation->startEnvironmentEmulation(1, \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, true);

    $collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addStoreFilter($this->storeManager->getStore()->getId())
        ->addAttributeToFilter('status', ['in' => $this->productStatus->getVisibleStatusIds()])
        ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', ['in' => $this->productVisibility->getVisibleInSiteIds()])
        ;

    $this->emulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation();
}
```

Comment: `startEnvironmentEmulation` worked for me. Thanks mate :)

Comment: perfect answer!!! +1 made my day :)

Comment: Working fine...!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $productCollectionFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
    $collection = $productCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $collection->addWebsiteFilter();

    // filter current store products
    $collection->addStoreFilter();
    $collection->setVisibility($objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility')->getVisibleInSiteIds());
    $collection->setPageSize(5);
    foreach ($collection as $product) {
        $output->writeln($product->getName());
    }
    return;
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Tried your code, still getting same error in exception.log

Comment: Try any of this $collection->addStoreFilter(1); or $collection->addStoreFilter(0,1);

Comment: `$collection->addStoreFilter(1);` worked for me, but other answer is more accurate. Thanks for taking time and answering my question. +1